# How can I get capital Angstrom symbol to appear in bibliography (using .bib file and natbib)?

Tags: symbols, bibliographies, natbib, macros

I have search all around but cannot seem to find the solution for getting a capital angstrom symbol (an "A" with a small circle above it) to appear in the bibliography of my dissertation. Instead, it appears as lower case "a" with circle above it.

The \AA command works just fine to generate the capital Angstrom symbol in the actual flow of my dissertation, but for some reason it doesn't work when used in the .bib file. Can someone point me to the corresponding command to get the capital Angstrom symbol to display properly in the .bib file?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping an extra pair of braces around it? I.e., {\AA}.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that isn't working - for both \AA and {\AA}, I get the lower-case angstrom symbol ("a" with circle on top).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
title={The unit {{\AA}ngström}},
```

should work

Comment: Well, if you get to use the letter ö, I don't see why not Å as well?

Comment: if it is in the title entry, then it will be converted to lowercase (except the very first letter) and the double `{{..}}` prevent it from converting

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `${\AA}$`, instead use `{\AA}` with amsmath.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you explain, where is the difference to [Herbert's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8955/95441), who also suggests using `{\AA}`? And I am not sure what amsmath should be good for in this context. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You can just put in your `.bib` file as:

`{{\AA}}`, it will display angstrom symbol in capital A.

Comment: What's the diffrence between your answer and the one from Herbert?

Comment: For displaying angstrom in capital A, it is {{\AA}} not {{\AA}ngstrom}, thats a difference Dear Mr. Picot.

Comment: `{{\AA}ngstrom}` have an angstrom in capital A as far as I know. So the answer is still the same as the one provided by Herbert `;-)`

Comment: {{\AA}ngstrom} will display word Angstrom , not display symbol Å, so for displaying only symbol  Å, you have to put {{\AA}} not {{\AA}ngstrom}. From beginning, this I want to say. Even after that  you have any doubt , you can freely to ask me, Thanks.