# How do I force the title of a bibliography item to not go into the margin?

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I have a citation for which the title is overflowing into the right margin.  Any ideas on how to force it to not go into the margin?

Here is my mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{leonard_crystal_1993,
  title = {Crystal and molecular structure of d({CGTAGATCTACG}) at 2.25 {{\AA}} resolution.},
  % title = {Crystal and molecular structure of d({CGTAG ATCTACG}) at 2.25 {{\AA}} resolution.}, % hack method
  volume = {234},
  issn = {0022-2836},
  url = {http://www.pdb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=119D},
  doi = {10.1006/jmbi.1993.1574},
  timestamp = {2015-09-02T12:35:06Z},
  urldate = {2015-08-31},
  journal = {{J}.{Mol}.{Biol}.},
  author = {Leonard, {G}. {A}. and {Hunter}, {W}. {N}.},
  month = apr,
  year = {1993},
  pages = {198--208},
  file = {PDB Snapshot:/myZotero/storage/A56WV6CM/explore.html:;Protein Data Bank .pdb File:/myZotero/storage/GI65SRAF/Leonard and Hunter - 1993 - Crystal and molecular structure of d(CGTAGATCTACG).pdb:},
  pmid = {8230199}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  style=ieee, % includes title, [square brackets], yes DOI, citestyle is weird
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  natbib=true,
  sorting=none,
  url=false,
  doi=true,
  isbn=false,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cite{leonard_crystal_1993}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Here is the unsatisfactory result.  Notice how the CGTAGATCTACG enters the 1.25in margin on the right.

[image]

I considered simply adding a space in the DNA sequence in to give it somewhere to wrap but I would think LaTeX should be able to handle this.

Comment: I found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8955/61946) the solution for how to make the angstrom symbol render correctly.  Change `{\AA}` to instead be `{{\AA}}`.

Comment: In case the four letters `A`, `C`, `G`, and `T` refer to base molecules in a DNA chain, I'd give the nod to allowing a line break only after groups of four letters *and* not employing a hyphenation character at the break point. Thus, I'd write `CGTA\hspace{0pt}GATC\hspace{0pt}TACG`. The `\hspace{0pt}` directives allow line breaks but won't be visible if no line break is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the four letters `A`, `C`, `G`, and `T` that make up the 12-letter "word" refer to base molecules in a DNA chain, I'd give the nod to (a) allowing a line break only after groups of four letters and (b) not employing a hyphenation character at the break point. Thus, I'd write

```
CGTA\hspace{0pt}GATC\hspace{0pt}TACG
```

The `\hspace{0pt}` directives allow line breaks but won't be visible if no line break is needed. If you do wish to employ a hyphenation character at the linebreak point, write the word as `CGTA\-GATC\-TACG` instead.

Regarding the angstrom symbol: I think the best way to handle this issue is to employ the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package and to write the quantity/unit combination as

```
{\relax \SI{2.25}{\angstrom}}
```

That way, the spacing between the quantity and the unit is guaranteed to be appropriate. The `\relax` part is there to keep `biber`/`biblatex` from complaining about a non-existing problem with lower-casing letters.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{xyz.bib}
@article{leonard_crystal_1993,
  title = {Crystal and molecular structure of d({CGTA\hspace{0pt}GATC\hspace{0pt}TACG}) 
           at {\relax \SI{2.25}{\angstrom}} resolution},
  volume = {234},
  issn = {0022-2836},
  url = {http://www.pdb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=119D},
  doi = {10.1006/jmbi.1993.1574},
  timestamp = {2015-09-02T12:35:06Z},
  urldate = {2015-08-31},
  journal = {J.Mol.Biol.},
  author = {Leonard, G. A. and Hunter, W. N.},
  month = apr,
  year = {1993},
  pages = {198--208},
  pmid = {8230199}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1in, hmargin=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  style=ieee, 
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  natbib=true,
  sorting=none,
  url=false,
  doi=true,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xyz.bib}

\usepackage{siunitx} % for "\SI" macro

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \cite{leonard_crystal_1993}
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a note for [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) users, to fully implement this solution, the title should be formated as: Crystal and molecular structure of d(CGTA<pre>{\hspace{0pt}}</pre>GATC<pre>{\hspace{0pt}}</pre>TACG) at <pre>{\relax \SI{2.25}{\angstrom}}</pre> resolution